# Is this the right way to implement my own filter in twig? (I want *minimal* whitespace between tags, not *no* whitespace between tags)

Tags: twig, twig-extension, twig-filter

I know that `apply spaceless` "isn't about optimisation", in Symfony's words.  But dammit, I dislike extraneous whitespace from being in my served files.

So I'm keen to use it.

But... I don't like how it reduces

```
<span>1</span>

<span>2</span>
```

to

```
<span>1</span><span>2</span>
```

As that results in the browser displaying `12`, rather than `1 2`.

In my mind whitespace between tags should be reduced to a single space, not to nothing.

```
<span>1</span> 

<span>2</span>
```

->

```
<span>1</span> <span>2</span>
```

So I thought I'd make a custom filter, `minimizeWhitespace`, and wrap my templates with `<% apply minimizeWhitespace %>`

This is what I came up with:

```
function minimizeWhitespace($s)
{
    return new \Twig\Markup(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $s->__toString()), 'UTF-8');
}

$TWIG_env->addFilter(
    new \Twig\TwigFilter('minimizeWhitespace', 'minimizeWhitespace')
);
```

This feels messy though - I'm taking their `\Twig\Markup` object, converting it to a string, running my regexp on it, and then creating a new `\Twig\Markup` object to return.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I wouldn't worry much about that. Do note that you could just mark the filter/function as [safe](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/advanced.html#automatic-escaping)

Comment: I'm being dense, how does that help? ‍♂️

Comment: Then you don't need to do `return new \Twig\Markup(...);` but you can just `return $html;`